# previously working script using keyup() does not work for one client

Tags: jquery

Years ago I wrote a really tiny script for a time interval entry. It is very simple and it worked fine for a long time until recently. Now it still works except from one mobile phone (Chrome 85 on Android 10). Standard configuration, no addons installed. Restarting did not help. It worked on that phone too - just few weeks ago. I tried three other mobile devices with exactly the same Chrome version, different Android versions (5, 7, and 10) and everything is okay there too.

I do not understand what makes the difference and I'd like to know where is the problem or how to debug it. I'm using JQuery only for my hobby projects, I don't have much experience.

The first input field is "hours" and only one digit is expected here. When the user enters the first character, the focus is automatically moved to "minutes". Examples:

- 1 3 0 [enter] -> 1h30m
- 2 5 [enter] -> 2h5m

The `0` in the hours field is selected. Normally it gets replaced by the key the user presses as first. Then the focus moves to minutes.

Now, with this new problem, when the user presses a key, the focus is first moved to minutes and then the all input goes to that field including the first key. It is not possible to enter hours. The [backspace] key does not work in "hours" field.

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="hours" min="0" name="hours" required type="number" value="0">
    :
    <input id="minutes" max="59" min="0" name="minutes" required type="number" value="0">
</form>
```

JQuery:

initial state:

```
$hours.focus();
$hours.select();
```

event handler:

```
$hours.keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length >= 1) {
        $minutes.focus();
        $minutes.select();
    }
});
```

where:

```
var $hours = $('#hours');
var $minutes = $('#minutes');
```